# How to know which concrete view consume motionEvent in Activity?

Tags: android, view

I'm building a HeatMap FrameWork which need to collect `MotionEvents` in every Activity:

```
Activity.dispathTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);
```

In fact, through `MotionEvent` I can get coordinates about event.

But How can I get Which concrete view consumes this `MotionEvent`?

Comment: you cannot, what do you need it for?

Comment: @pskink Our PM want to know, the user touched which view, and show this in the heat map.